# EF Core with property that is interchangeable

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to create entity in EF core that enables me to use different types of classes of same interface type.

e.g.

```
interface IAnimal 
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    int weight { get; set; }
}

class Dog : IAnimal 
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    int weight { get; set; }
    bool IsGood { get; set; }
}

class Cat : IAnimal 
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    int weight { get; set; }
    bool IsHellSpawn { get; set; }
}

class PetOwner 
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string name { get; set; }
    IAnimal myPet { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationDbContext has following enties for the classes.

```
public DbSet<Dog> Dog { get; set; }
public DbSet<Cat> Cat { get; set; }
public DbSet<PetOwner> PetOwner { get; set;}
```

In one of the business logic processes, I might have function that acts differently depending on type of class it is:

```
var petOwner = service.getPetOwner();

if (petOwner.myPet is Dog)
{
    petOwner.myPet.IsGood = true;
}
else if (petOwner.myPet is Cat) 
{
    petOwner.myPet.IsHellSpawn = true;
}
```

Comment: You could, in ealier editions of EF, I'm not sure if they kept it. At first glance it seems nice and special, but it really just gets in your way every step. Let your owner have a list of dog and a list of cat. And if you get horses, too, add a list of horse. Because while polymorphism is cool in C#, as soon as you hit a boundary (lets say the database or a REST backend on the other side) it breaks down and you have to find a special solution just for that. So my advice is to keep it simple and don't do it. Not an answer though, I don't know how to technically do it, because we dropped it.

Comment: You mean like `MyFunction<T>(...) where T:IAnimal => db.Set<T>()....` ?

Comment: @nvoigt i might just stick to that format, polymorphism is really cool, but like you said db and other services that cannot handle it neatly fall over.

Answer (score 0):

How is it EF-related? Any of these entities can be `DbSet` classes. Or you can have base class `IAnimal` and derived classes, and you decide on the way they are stored in the database -

Additionally, you can use `is` operator with assignment, like this:

```
var petOwner = service.getPetOwner();

if (petOwner.myPet is Dog dog)
{
    dog.IsGood = true;
}
else if (petOwner.myPet is Cat cat) 
{
    cat.IsHellSpawn = true;
}
```

but I am not sure it's any better that what you have.

Comment: Dog and Cat class have DbSet, so depending on what PetOwner has as myPet, it will either store in Cat or Dog table. Updated the question with the missing context.